# What is the name of this part?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I thought it was called a "jog dial" but I can't find any parts by that name.

[image]

[image]

There are five pins on the back and one on each side.

What is it called and how can I find a replacement?

It is similar to this momentary switch but it does not have the same number of pins and may actually be an entirely different component:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/231618098407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These switches are called and categorized in several ways:

- Navigation Switch
- Lever Switch
- Tactile Switch

The first ones I found are from Multicomp and they have three pins MCPL3-BC-V and MCPL3-AC-V. Also similar ones from APEM PL3BCV. Next I found LY series from AKEYS (also have different branding). See picture below:
[image: Navigation Lever Switches]

As you can see there is 5pin version LY-K8-02, although the handle looks not the same. And lastly I found that switches are also manufactured by JIANFU but seems no 5pin there.

Comment: I'm accepting this as it names the part and closely matches the unit in the photos. There may not be a direct replacement available anymore or the part may have been customized with a different handle.

Comment: I just dig up this link http://www.pengxinkj.com/ProductsShow_en.asp?id=113. This looks like the best match. Model number MT11MG.

Answer (score 2):

The generic name for this seems to be: 5-way navigation switch.

Using google I looked at a lot of pictures of this type of switch but did not spot one that use 5 SMD terminals all in one row like your pictures show.